# Is this a real Technic cloak?

Tags: part-identification, technic, clone-brands

I found a cloak piece in some used LEGO I bought from a former LEGO employee. The cloak does not say LEGO on it, but it fits perfectly onto Technic figures with a satisfying pop and matches the contours of their bodies.

Is this a real LEGO piece?

I should note that the LEGO I bought had a small amount of junk mixed in from other toy brands.

[image]

[image]

Comment: None of the Technic figures had cloaks, so I would guess this is not Lego. Lots of playmobil figures have cloaks...

Comment: The way It molds around his shoulders does seem like it fits snug as a bug, but in all my youth growing up with these Large Action figures, I've never seen the "Technic Theme" waver into fantasy based comic book heroism, evil space cyborgs, yes, but never capes.  Can you list the non-LEGO brands that came with the box?

Comment: Is this an off-brand head? Since when do LEGO minifigs have noses?

Comment: @MechMK1 This is not a minifigure, but a [LEGO Technic figure](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?catType=M&catString=36).

Comment: @zovits I have played with a lot of LEGO Technic as a kid, but I have never come across any of those. I am shocked that some of those were released in 1986. I wonder if they were more popular in the US than in Europe.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

this is a Playmobil cape, from the [Zorro figure](http://www.16bit.com/fotd/111124-playmobil-5203-zorro.asp#)

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Yeah, what *Michael Verschaeve* suggested in comments.  Looks like a *Playmobil* cloak.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: On the grey example, the part around the neck in the front looks different from the OP.